# Split list into duplicate and non-duplicate lists

Tags: c#, linq

So far I have this:

```
List<Item> duplicates = items.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
    .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1)).ToList();

List<Item> nonDuplicates = items.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
    .Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this (i.e. one select)?

**Example input:**

```
Id     Value (added for some perspective)
--     -----
1       12
1      909
1231     0
1      577
```

**Example Output:**

```
duplicates     -> {1, 909}, {1, 577}
non-duplicates -> {1, 12},  {1231, 0}
```

Comment: You may wish to provide an example of input and expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *really* want to avoid doing the actual grouping more than once, and thus avoid iterating the source sequence more than once, you can group the items, materialize that query into a list, and then grab the info that you want from that list.

```
var query = items.GroupBy(x => x.id)
    .ToList();

var duplicates = query.SelectMany(group => group.Skip(1));
var nonDuplicates = query.Select(group => group.First());
```

Having said that, grouping items isn't *particularly* expensive of an operation, so this may not actually be a particularly huge win.  Odds are reasonably high that your existing code is "good enough".

I'd be mostly interested in doing this if I wasn't confident that the source sequence would return the same items if iterated multiple times, or if it's say an `IQueryable` that needs to do a round trip to the database to get the items.  In those cases this is a change worth implementing.

Answer (score 2):

Get the first one for each Id, then use `Except` to get the others.

```
List<Item> nonDupes = items.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
List<Item> dupes = items.Except(nonDupes).ToList();
```

This is, however, assuming that `Equals` hasn't been overridden to be simply the `Id`.

**EDIT**: And here's a fiddle: http://dotnetfiddle.net/4GaPK4

Comment: This is still iterating the source sequence multiple times.  Also, if the exact same item (using whatever definition of equality the type has defined for itself) is in the list multiple times then this code won't include the duplicate in the list of duplicates (or it will only include one of the two duplicates in the duplicate listing, depending on whether or not one of them made it into the "non-dupe" list.

Comment: You're right, I did assume that the exact same reference wouldn't appear twice.

Comment: Technically they could even be items with different references, as long as they're equal according to whatever the implementation of the `Equals` method is.  It could be overridden to perform value semantics, or to define equality as having an identical ID, for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = items.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                        .Select(g => new { 
                                      Dups = g.Where(g.Count > 1), 
                                     NonDups = g.Where(g.Count == 1), })
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Did you try it? First of all, it will not be of type `List<Item>`

Answer (score 0):

Not in one query, but arguably more efficient approach can be achieved by using `DistinctBy` from [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/):

```
var nonDuplicates = items.DistinctBy(i => i.Id);
var duplicates = items.Except(nonDuplicates);
```

Comment: This is still iterating the source sequence multiple times.  Also, if the exact same item (using whatever definition of equality the type has defined for itself) is in the list multiple times then this code won't include the duplicate in the list of duplicates.

Comment: It's very easy to prevent it from reiterating by putting `items = items.ToArray();` in the beginning as for the second comment you are right.